# Scale remote image to device height and width

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to build an android app which has a ScrollView, where an image (remote URL) fills up the screen (with a marginTop, marginLeft, marginRight and marginBottom set to around 5dp ) and when you scroll down, you find further UI components.

I am finding it difficult to scale the image to the exact dimensions. There is no control on the size of the image. Some could be small, some could be big. If its small, I would like to stretch it to fit the screen. My XML looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:indeterminate="true" 
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/movieImageLoading"/>

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/headerImage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/movie_image"></ImageView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerImage"
        android:text="save" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

which is wrong, can somebody help me out please ?

Thank you..

Comment: Saying "this is wrong" isn't helpful. What's wrong? What's the behaviour that you're seeing? Ideally, post a screenshot of what's happening, and a mockup of how you'd like it to look

Comment: Hi Matt. Have specified the behavior in Pratik's answer below.
Screenshots : 
http://postimage.org/image/wthseojsf/
http://postimage.org/image/is2rtogah/

Comment: I haven't tried it right now, but shouldn't `centerInside` be the desired scaletype? From the documentation it seems to do exactly what you want. EDIT:  see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: Hi Thrakbad, tried that, no luck tho :(

Answer (score 0):

try this layout

Make your button as bottom to fix and set the image view above the button with fill parent and last specify the progress bar

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" > <!-- here make wrap to fill -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="save"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/headerImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/save2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="movie_image"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" >
    </ImageView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/movieImageLoading"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Pratik. I still see the same behavior tho. The smaller images seem to scale X and Y, but is not stretched to the bottom. The bigger images seem to grow beyond the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Screenshots : 

http://postimage.org/image/wthseojsf/

http://postimage.org/image/is2rtogah/

Comment: Hi I have updated my answer with small change please check it. You have to relativelayout height as fill_parent instead of wrap_content

Comment: I get a similar output, its still not scaling ont he 'height' :(